# Unexpected character when using node-webcrypto-ossl

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules

I am using the node-webcrypto-ossl in angular 4 but when i try to execute some function i keep getting this,

```
Module parse failed: /Users/---/---/webapp/node_modules/node-webcrypto-ossl/build/Release/nodessl.node Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably environmental. The package works fine on Windows, I would start by making sure I was using latest stable npm and node.